# Blender 2.7 how to find spotlight lookAt/target using script

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender, blender-2.61, blender-2.67

I am having a hard time figuring out how to find spotlight lookAt/Target point. I need it to export some light information in a file so that I will able to use them with OpenGL and render a scene.

So far have this code

```
with open(bpy.path.abspath("//Taest.txt"), "w", encoding="utf8", newline="\n") as f:
        fw = f.write
        #fw("testing file write")
        #for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        for ob in bpy.data.objects:
            if ob.type == "LAMP" :
                la = ob.data

                fw(la.type + " " + la.name + "\n")
                fw(vec3ToStr(ob.location) + "\n")
                fw(colorToStr(la.color) + "\n")
                fw(str(la.energy) + "\n")

                #if la.type == "AREA" :
                #    print("\tAREA " + la.name)

                if la.type == "POINT" :
                    fw(str(la.distance) + "\n")
                    fw(str(la.quadratic_attenuation) + "\n")
                    fw(str(la.linear_attenuation) + "\n")


                if la.type == "SPOT" :
                    fw(str(la.distance) + "\n")
                    fw(str(la.quadratic_attenuation) + "\n")
                    fw(str(la.linear_attenuation) + "\n")
                    fw(str(la.spot_size) + "\n")
                    #empty = bpy.data.meshes.ne(type='PLAIN_AXES')
                    me = bpy.data.meshes.new("test Mesh")
                    obn = bpy.data.objects.new("test Obj" , me)
                    scn = bpy.context.scene
                    scn.objects.link(obn)
                    obn.location = ob.location #ob.shadow_buffer_clip_end <<< this is where i have trouble figuring out what to do ??
                    fw(vec3ToStr(me .location) + "\n") 
                    obn.delete()
```

Solved

```
mat = ob.matrix_world
            end = mat * Vector((0, 0, -la.shadow_buffer_clip_end))
            fw(vec3ToStr(end) + "\n")
```

Comment: Post your answer as an answer to the question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
mat = ob.matrix_world
            end = mat * Vector((0, 0, -la.shadow_buffer_clip_end))
            fw(vec3ToStr(end) + "\n")
```

Its the same also for camera lookAt if case you need

```
mat = ob.matrix_world
        end = mat * Vector((0, 0, -la.shadow_buffer_clip_end))
        fw(vec3ToStr(end) + "\n")
```